# Synchronizing Editor with changes in the Properties View

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a custom editor with attached Properties view(default properties view provide by eclipse). In the editor I have a `TreeViewer` for which I am displaying the selected node properties in properties view.

TreeViewer is acting on XML file. In the `createpartControl` method I am setting the selection provider.

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    .........       
    treeViewer.getTree().setHeaderVisible(true);
    treeViewer.getTree().setLinesVisible(true);
    treeViewer.setContentProvider(new CopybookXMLEditorContentProvider());

    //creating columns
    createColumns(treeColLayout);
    //setting tree input
    treeViewer.setInput(inputFileDoc.getDocumentElement());
    //adding tree to workbench selection service for providing properties
    getSite().setSelectionProvider(treeViewer);
    .....
}
```

Since the selection will be a DOM node I have added an adapter which provide an `IPropertySourceProvider` object.

```
public <T> T getAdapter(Object adaptableObject, Class<T> adapterType) {
    if(adaptableObject instanceof Node && adapterType == IPropertySourceProvider.class){
        return (T) new CopybookXMLEditorPropertyProvider(((Node)adaptableObject));
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Class<?>[] getAdapterList() {
    return new Class[]{IPropertySourceProvider.class};
}
```

In the class implementing the `IPropertySourceProvider` interface I am getting the attributes from the passed node and setting it in a POJO class. I am pasing this object to `IPropertySource` class in the `getPropertySource()` method.

```
public class CopybookXMLEditorPropertyProvider implements IPropertySourceProvider {

private Node selectedNode;

public CopybookXMLEditorPropertyProvider(Node selectedNode) {
    this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
}

@Override
public IPropertySource getPropertySource(Object object) {
    CopybookItem item = prepareItemValues();
    return new CopybookXMLEditorPropertySource(item);
}

private CopybookItem prepareItemValues() {
    CopybookItem item = new CopybookItem();

    Node nameNode = selectedNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name");
    if(nameNode!=null) {
        item.setCopybookFieldName(nameNode.getNodeValue());
    }
    ....
    return item;
}
```

**CopybookItem class**

```
public class CopybookItem {

private String copybookFieldName = CommonConstants.EMPTY_STRING;
.......


public String getCopybookFieldName() {
    return copybookFieldName;
}

public void setCopybookFieldName(String copybookFieldName) {
    this.copybookFieldName = copybookFieldName;
}
//....remaining getter setters
```

}

In the class implementing`IPropertySource` interface

```
public class CopybookXMLEditorPropertySource implements IPropertySource{

private CopybookItem copybookItem;

public CopybookXMLEditorPropertySource(CopybookItem copybookItem) {
    this.copybookItem = copybookItem;
}

@Override
public Object getEditableValue() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public IPropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
    IPropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescArr = new IPropertyDescriptor[7];
    TextPropertyDescriptor javaBeanDescriptor = new TextPropertyDescriptor("javaBean", "Java Property Name");
    .....
    return propertyDescArr;
}

@Override
public Object getPropertyValue(Object id) {
    String property = (String)id;
    switch (property) {
        case "javaBean":
            return copybookItem.getJavaPropertyName();
        ....
    }
}

@Override
public void setPropertyValue(Object id, Object value) {
    String property = (String)id;
    String propertyvalue = String.valueOf(value);
    switch (property) {
        case "javaBean":
             copybookItem.setJavaPropertyName(propertyvalue);
            ...more cases
    }
}
```

The properties are editable so once user changes them I want to synchronize the tree viewer with the changes and mark the editor dirty. How can I listen to those changes and update the original XML node in tree viewer.

Can anybody give some pointers on how to achieve this.
Thanks!!

Comment: What are you using for the `IPropertySource`? What are you doing in the `setPropertyValue` method?

Comment: I have an `IPropertySourceProvider` where I extract all the attributes from selected node and set it in a bean class, I pass this bean to `IPropertySource`. In `setPropertyValue` right now I am just updating that bean with new value which user enters.

Comment: So refresh the tree viewer as well in setPropertyValue. Your question is so lacking in detail that it isn't really possible to say any more.

Comment: I have added some code listings maybe that will help. How can I get the tree viewer in setpropertyValue method?

Comment: It is up to you to add code to the property source to tell it about the tree viewer.

Comment: Can you provide some hint on how can I get the current tree viewer , editor instance in property source class?

Comment: There are plenty of well documented ways to get the active editor, such as `IWorkbenchPage.getActiveEditor`. But it may well be better to use a listener pattern and have the editor listen for change messages from items.